# FINDSTR result without newline in text csv

Tags: batch-file

im currently want to try get a result from findstr in batchfile that result inserted to csv file without newline

so this is code that i already tried

```
echo Services,Tanggal,Hit1,Hit2 >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,31) DO (
     if %%A LEQ 9 (
        echo | set /p ="%namaService%,0%%A/%tanggal%," >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv 
        echo | FINDSTR /R /N "0%%A/%tanggal%.*%namaService%" osb_server1\access* | FIND /C ":" >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv
        echo | FINDSTR /R /N "0%%A/%tanggal%.*%namaService%" osb_server2\access* | FIND /C ":" >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv

     ) else (
        echo | set /p ="%namaService%,%%A/%tanggal%," >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv 
        echo | FINDSTR /R /N "%%A/%tanggal%.*%namaService%" osb_server1\access* | FIND /C ":" >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv 
        echo | FINDSTR /R /N "%%A/%tanggal%.*%namaService%" osb_server2\access* | FIND /C ":" >> Summary_%tanggal:/=-%_%namaService:/=-%.csv 

     )
)
```

the code is a success but the formating should have be like csv file, each line in csv text for each loop. this is my current output

```
Services,Tanggal,Hit1,Hit2 
mobile-rest-ios,01/Aug/2019,10127
9980
mobile-rest-ios,02/Aug/2019,7825
7212
mobile-rest-ios,03/Aug/2019,4256
4206
mobile-rest-ios,04/Aug/2019,2754
2980
mobile-rest-ios,05/Aug/2019,6915
6757
mobile-rest-ios,06/Aug/2019,7362
6868
mobile-rest-ios,07/Aug/2019,6819
6934
mobile-rest-ios,08/Aug/2019,5698
5441
mobile-rest-ios,09/Aug/2019,5503
5383
mobile-rest-ios,10/Aug/2019,3719
3724
mobile-rest-ios,11/Aug/2019,2586
2621
mobile-rest-ios,12/Aug/2019,5964
5875
mobile-rest-ios,13/Aug/2019,6061
6305
mobile-rest-ios,14/Aug/2019,6167
6240
mobile-rest-ios,15/Aug/2019,5736
5476
mobile-rest-ios,16/Aug/2019,4366
4423
mobile-rest-ios,17/Aug/2019,2352
2358
mobile-rest-ios,18/Aug/2019,2509
2551
mobile-rest-ios,19/Aug/2019,5994
6133
mobile-rest-ios,20/Aug/2019,5662
6140
mobile-rest-ios,21/Aug/2019,5943
5797
mobile-rest-ios,22/Aug/2019,5926
6251
mobile-rest-ios,23/Aug/2019,4844
5006
mobile-rest-ios,24/Aug/2019,2887
3109
mobile-rest-ios,25/Aug/2019,2814
2692
mobile-rest-ios,26/Aug/2019,6082
5994
mobile-rest-ios,27/Aug/2019,6029
5831
mobile-rest-ios,28/Aug/2019,6436
6486
mobile-rest-ios,29/Aug/2019,3384
3251
mobile-rest-ios,30/Aug/2019,0
0
mobile-rest-ios,31/Aug/2019,0
0
Total,,152720
```

what the output that i expected is like this

```
Services,Tanggal,Hit 
mobile-rest-ios,01/Aug/2019,10127,9980
mobile-rest-ios,02/Aug/2019,7825,7212
mobile-rest-ios,03/Aug/2019,4256,4206
mobile-rest-ios,04/Aug/2019,2754,2980
mobile-rest-ios,05/Aug/2019,6915,6757
mobile-rest-ios,06/Aug/2019,7362,6868
mobile-rest-ios,07/Aug/2019,6819,6934
mobile-rest-ios,08/Aug/2019,5698,5441
mobile-rest-ios,09/Aug/2019,5503,5383
mobile-rest-ios,10/Aug/2019,3719,3724
mobile-rest-ios,11/Aug/2019,2586,2621
mobile-rest-ios,12/Aug/2019,5964,5875
mobile-rest-ios,13/Aug/2019,6061,6305
mobile-rest-ios,14/Aug/2019,6167,6240
mobile-rest-ios,15/Aug/2019,5736,5476
mobile-rest-ios,16/Aug/2019,4366,4423
mobile-rest-ios,17/Aug/2019,2352,2358
mobile-rest-ios,18/Aug/2019,2509,2551
mobile-rest-ios,19/Aug/2019,5994,6133
mobile-rest-ios,20/Aug/2019,5662,6140
mobile-rest-ios,21/Aug/2019,5943,5797
mobile-rest-ios,22/Aug/2019,5926,6251
mobile-rest-ios,23/Aug/2019,4844,5006
mobile-rest-ios,24/Aug/2019,2887,3109
mobile-rest-ios,25/Aug/2019,2814,2692
mobile-rest-ios,26/Aug/2019,6082,5994
mobile-rest-ios,27/Aug/2019,6029,5831
mobile-rest-ios,28/Aug/2019,6436,6486
mobile-rest-ios,29/Aug/2019,3384,3251
mobile-rest-ios,30/Aug/2019,0,0
mobile-rest-ios,31/Aug/2019,0,0
Total,,152720,135512
```

Comment: You are not providing input examples, I will therefore assume that the second `findstr` line in both code blocks are producing the second line, I would therefore say, rather get your results, then combine the results to a single string and echo to file.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard hai thank you for you feedback, i was gonna put my set input for the variable needed but im afraid the code gonna kinda long. so i only ask for the findstr problem that keep giving newline each findstr result. Would you kindly help me out how to make that findstr wont producing newline? thank you so much, im still learning here